# Tags "Crusades" vs "Crusaders"

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-merge

Both tags [crusades](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusades) and [crusaders](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusaders) exist presently.

All the questions in the latter, except [this one](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/50186/is-or-was-there-a-version-of-the-maltese-cross-with-the-right-arrowhead-missin), also use the first tag.

Should this situation be modified, or do both tags serve a different (and useful) purpose?

Comment: Here, I guess that a strict observation and analysis of possible problems, plusses or downsides might be better kept to the Q itself, not 'a' solution, but guesses at possible ones? Or just fleshed out. But since you chose to self-answer anyway (which is fine, btw) : perhaps better frame 'the problem' separately and focus your answer on *your* solution? (Formally: Am having trouble voting on this, as 'Q is leading'…)

Answer (score -1):

I deleted my previous answer where I disagreed with the OP's idea that there is a separate case for both [crusades](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusades) and [crusaders](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusaders). Reading Jones' 'Crusaders' has made me change my mind, so I'm ready to present a case for both tags here.

### General Idea

1. [crusades](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusades) for questions relating to all officially declared Crusades, in other words the Crusades to the Holy Land, as well as the Reconquista, the Northern Crusades, anti-Ottoman Crusades alongside the internal Christian strifes (e.g., the Albigensian Crusade).
2. [crusaders](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusaders) for questions relating to individuals who 'took the cross', even if they were not participants on an official Crusade, and for topics that relate to the motivations of participating in religious wars.

### Examples

- **Questions which relate to any specific crusader instead of the greater political-economic context of a Crusade would use [crusaders](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusaders):**

  - [Sigurd of Norway's expedition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigurd_I_of_Norway) would be tagged [crusaders](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusaders) as the Pope did not declare it an official Crusade;
  - This [question on William Marshall](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/43345/any-information-about-what-william-marshall-guillaume-le-marechal-did-in-the-h) would be tagged [crusaders](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusaders) but not [crusades](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusades) as it relates to William's taking of the cross and fighting for his religion, but doesn't directly relate to a specific Crusade;
  - This [question on Stephen of Blois](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/41239/why-did-stephen-ii-of-blois-father-of-king-stephen-of-england-abandon-the-firs) would be tagged [crusaders](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusaders) but not [crusades](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusades) as the question is about the specifics of one man's actions on a Crusade and the question does not relate to the First Crusade as an event;
- **Questions which relate to the greater context of Crusades as events would use [crusades](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusades):**

  - This [question on Richard's actions](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/12607/how-did-richard-i-sail-through-the-strait-of-gibraltar) would retain both [crusades](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusades) and [crusaders](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusaders) as it relates to Richard's crusade as directed by Richard but also the greater political context;
- **Questions which relate to crusading organizations but not a specific crusader nor a specific Crusade would not include either tag:**

  - This [question on military orders](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/11881/what-specific-training-did-members-of-medieval-military-orders-get) does not specifically relate to either the Crusades or crusading as an action, but rather the internal organization of specific polities and would be tagged [templars](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/templars)/[knights-templar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knights-templar) and [hospitallers](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hospitallers)/[knights-hospitaller](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/knights-hospitaller);
  - This [question on Knights Templar](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/33/when-did-the-knights-templar-dissolve-and-why) would not have either [crusades](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusades) nor [crusaders](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crusaders) as their dissolution has nothing to do with either of those;

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: See here how I changed my opinions on this topic :)